# Is it possible to select from 2 tables without using a where clause?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Here's my problem, I have 2 tables: products and bids

In the products table I have the product name, id, price (buyitnow) and auction type.

Now in my bids, I have bids_id, bids_item, bids_amount. I am trying to show newly listed product either an auction or a Buy it now. I am trying to show the bids price and buyit now price.

Here's the SQL code I am working with:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   products, 
       bids 
WHERE  enddate > Now() 
       AND products.id = bids.bids_item 
ORDER  BY date DESC 
LIMIT  16
```

Now the problem with that statement is it only shows auction listings with a row in the bids table, and not always does an item have that row, because no ones either bid or it's a buy it now. I am using a simple foreach for that statement.

I am trying to use the variables:

```
$product->bids_amount; //auction
$product->price; //bin
```

How can I resolve this problem, here's my tables:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course.  You *want* to use an `on` clause.  In fact, you should simply not use comma in the `from` clause . . . a simple rule:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   products JOIN
       bids 
       ON products.id = bids.bids_item AND enddate > Now()  
ORDER  BY date DESC 
LIMIT  16
```

Then, if you want to keep all products, use `LEFT JOIN`.  This keeps all records in the first table:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   products LEFT JOIN
       bids 
       ON products.id = bids.bids_item AND enddate > Now()  
ORDER  BY date DESC 
LIMIT  16
```

Comment: Thank you, that's sorted it. Can you explain what you mean by keep all products use left join?

Comment: The `left join` will keep everything in the first table even if there is no match.